# Forwarding adb ports causes protocol fault error

Tags: android, ssh, adb

My situation is as follows: I use my eclipse+adt on local machine (DESKTOP - Ubuntu 11.10). I connect to it through ssh from remote machine (LAPTOP - Windows 7) for better eclipse performance. I want to have my device connected to the LAPTOP but use eclipse (with full logcat, apk installing features) on DESKTOP. I guess I need to forward adbd port from DESKTOP to LAPTOP. What I do:

on DESKTOP

```
adb kill-server
```

on LAPTOP (through putty gui)

```
ssh -R 5037:localhost:5037 user@DESKTOP
```

on DESKTOP

```
adb devices
```

Last command returns an error:

```
system/core/adb/adb.c::main():Handling commandline()
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_query():adb_query: host:devices
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: host:version
system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3 len=4: 30303063 000c
system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=3 len=12: 686f73743a76657273696f6e host:version
system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 wanted=4
system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=3 disconnected
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect: service host:devices
error: protocol fault (no status)
```

I am not sure what it means but it seems to be no return answer from adbd on LAPTOP to adb client on desktop.

Adb version is the same on both computers.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: If somebody would still check this: I have reinstalled the ADB and it worked fine. It might be possible that I used 32BIT ADB on LAPTOP and 64BIT ADB on DESKTOP. Not really sure if this is relevant.